# Form value object doesn't update when updating input fields from UI in Angular 14 (Reactive form) even though form control values are updated

Tags: forms, angular-reactive-forms, angular14, form-control, formgroups

When I am trying to update the form control from UI, the form value is not updating. The form shows status as "INVALID" even though all the formControls are valid. The form value object doesn't have updated data. Following is the console.log of the form after updating input fields from UI(I have trimmed the extra properties of the form object and kept only the required ones):

```
 {
  "controls": {
    "type": {
        "value": "Jira",
        "status": "VALID",
        "errors": null,
    },
    "cloudEnv": {
        "value": false,
        "status": "VALID",
        "errors": null,
    },
    "connectionName": {
        "value": "test",
        "status": "VALID",
        "errors": null,
    },
    "baseUrl": {
        "value": "test",
        "status": "VALID",
        "errors": null,
    },
    "username": {
        "value": "SUPERADMIN",
        "status": "VALID",
        "errors": null,
    },
    "apiEndPoint": {
        "value": "etst",
        "status": "VALID",
        "errors": null,
    }
    
  },
  "value":{
    "type": "test",
    "cloudEnv": false,
    "connectionName": "",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "username": "",
    "apiEndPoint": "",
  },
  "status": "INVALID"
}
```

When I try to update using `testForm.updateValueandValidity()`, it updates the form value object.
I have initialized the form like below:

```
testForm:FormGroup<any> = new FormGroup({});
```

And all the form controls are initialised like below:

```
connection = {
    'type': 'test',
    'cloudEnv': false,
    'connectionName': '',
    'baseUrl': '',
    'username': '',
    'apiEndPoint': '',
}

for (let key in connection) {
          this.testForm.controls[key] = new FormControl({ value: connection[key], disabled: false }, [Validators.required])
        }
```

Comment: Hi can you create a minimal, reproducible example in StackBlitz?